# A-Frame wrapCount shows 40 when I manually change it to 100.

Tags: aframe

When using text in AFrame I set the wrapCount to 100 in order to get a wider text block but when I review the page after it shows up as 40. Am I doing something wrong? Is 40 characters hard coded in version 5? I'm working on this http://www.cablecenter.org/vr/chof2017/ and made a text block 100 wrapCount but it still looks like 40. Is this a known issue? 
**UPDATE** Figured it out. wrapCount needs to be written as "wrap-count" with a dash. I had it written as one word as in "wrapCount." Example:

```
<a-text width="10" wrap-count="100" position="0 1.25 -5" color="#000" align="left" visible="true" value="wrapcount code for large text blocks to increase the width of the paragraph.">
```

I increased width to 10 to increase the size of the text. If I'd kept the width at 2 or 3 the text would be too small to read.

http://codepen.io/luiting57/pen/rmrJEm

Comment: What means "solved" in your title?

Comment: It means I figured out the problem after I posted the question. The docs are very unhelpful in understanding how to write this. The A-Frame docs show word count and wordCount and nowhere does it show word-count.

Comment: In that case it's better to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Right. Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the text component property is named wrapCount, but when using the a-text primitive there is an A-Frame convention where camelCase becomes hyphenated-lowercase ... so for a-text you use wrap-count